# De-Skewing image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I am unable to figure out how does this deskew is working

```
def deskew(img):
    m = cv2.moments(img)
    if abs(m['mu02']) < 1e-2:
        return img.copy()
    skew = m['mu11']/m['mu02']
    M = np.float32([[1, skew, -0.5*SZ*skew], [0, 1, 0]])
    img = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(SZ, SZ),flags=affine_flags)
    return img
```

> I know that the moment is a quantitative measure of the shape.
>
> In image processing, the moments give information about the total
>   area or Intensity, the centroid of the shape and the orientation of the
>   shape.
>
> Area or total Mass:-
>
> The zeroth moment M(0,0) gives the total Mass or Area.
>
> In image processing, the M(0,0) is the sum of all the pixels and if it is a binary image then sum of pixels gives the area.
>
> Center of mass or Centroid:-       When the first moment is divided by
>   the total mass then it gives the centroid.
>
> Centroid is that point where the shape is perfectly balanced on the
>   tip of the pin.
>
> M(0,1)/M(0,0) ,M(1,0)/M(0,0)

Answer (score 0):

I think the image from the [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dd/d3b/tutorial_py_svm_opencv.html) you got the code from gives the intuitive idea pretty well:

[image]

To deskew the image, they used [skewness](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Skewness) on x axis (**mu02**)  relative to the variance **mu11**. They used [shear matrix](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Shear_matrix)  with inverse of image skewness, which is why in `skew = m['mu11']/m['mu02']` **mu02** and **mu11** fraction is flipped. To deskew relative to the center of the top of the image, rather than the (0,0) point, they also used [translation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Translation_(geometry)), which is where you get `M[0, 2] = -0.5*SZ*skew`